# How to pass multiple where condition to the SQL in Symfony?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to pass multiple where condition to the given query. These are my condtions.

```
// Conditions
    $wheres = array(
        "v.id111" => "AUDI",
        "v.id112" => "A3",
    );
```

The keys are the field name and value are to be searched.

I have tried the `foreach` condition to get the fieldname and value.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder("v")
    ->distinct()
    ->select($selectFields);

// Where conditions.
if (!is_null($wheres)) {
    foreach ($wheres as $fieldName => $condition) {
        $query->andWhere("$fieldName = :condition")
            ->setParameter("condition", $condition);
    }
}

$records = $query->orderBy($selectFields)
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getResult();

dd($records);
```

The query looks correct to me but I am getting empty result.

Comment: Not sure if doctrine can handle same parameter names `:condition`. Try to use different names like `:condition1`, `:condition2` etc

Comment: @u_mulder Yes I think you are right. I will update my answer. Let me know what other solutions can you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($wheres as $fieldName => $condition) {
    $c +=1;
    $query->andWhere("$fieldName = :value$c")
        ->setParameter("value$c", $condition);
}
```